# Mock static Methods in ScalaTests or Spec2

Tags: java, scala, mocking

I would like to use scala unit tests in my current maven/java project because of its BDD features. However, some of my model classes have static CRUDE methods such as Edit.save(). There is any technique where I can mock the implicit calls to inner static methods in Scala?

For regular Java tests this is easily done using PowerMock annotations. My question is how we can do the same using any scala test framework (ScalaTest, Specs2).

I learned that **ScalaMock** could help with that but the '*GeneratedMockFactory*' trait is not present on their maven dependency (listed bellow). It seems to work only on SBT projects.

My scala test libraries:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.M5b</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalamock</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalamock-scalatest-support_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is how my scala tests looks like today:

```
package com.foo.edit

import org.scalatest._
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
import com.foo.models.Edit

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner]) // This line binds the test with maven-surefire runner
class EditSpec extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchers {

  "Edit" should "update name and website" in {
    val document = new util.HashMap[String, String]() {
      put("name", "A Name")
      put("website", "www.domain.com")
    }

    // This is the test subject, it's a Java class
    val edit = new Edit().modifiers(new util.HashMap[String, String]() {
      put("name", "Another Name")
      put("website", "http://site.org")
    });

    val result = edit.merge(document); // Here it calls Edit.save(document)
                                       // Want to stub this.

    assert(result.get("name") === "Another Name");
    assert(result.get("website") === "http://site.org");
  }
}
```